# How can I reset Aborted_connects in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

A recent issue in our network caused a large number of aborted connects, which is now being displayed on the health dashboard of our web application as a potential issue.

Aside from restarting MySQL, is there a way to reset `Aborted_connects` to 0? I have tried `flush hosts` and `flush status`, but they do not reset `Aborted_connects`

EDIT : MySQL 5.7.24

Comment: Did `FLUSH GLOBAL STATUS` acheive this? What MySQL version? Messy but you could gdb attach to the process and set `aborted_connects=0`.

Comment: MySQL 5.7.24. `FLUSH GLOBAL STATUS` tells me `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

Comment: Sorry about syntax, was thinking 'SET [GLOBAL|SESSION]` applied to flush too.

Comment: Plan B:  Get a dashboard that looks at the _change_ in that Status, not the value-since-restsrt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `FLUSH STATUS` doesn't reset this is because its a function in MySQL rather than a simple variable ([code ref](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/sql/mysqld.cc#L6818)).

Using [gdb assignment](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Assignment.html#Assignment), you should be able to:

```
gdb -p $(pidof mysqld) -batch \
  -ex 'set variable Connection_handler_manager::m_instance->m_aborted_connects = 0L' \
  -ex continue \
  -ex quit
```

Otherwise you don't have much choice apart from a restart.